# Does 'require' in Ruby not include subfolders automatically?

Tags: ruby, require

If I have this folder structure:

```
rexml
rexml/document
```

Is the following syntax not a recursive reference that includes everything below it?

```
require 'rexml'
```

Or do I need to write the following if I also want to access what's in `'document'`?:

```
require 'rexml/document'
```

The reason I'm confused is I see some code where the author writes both require statements one after the other:

```
require 'rexml'
require 'rexml/document'
```

I wasn't sure if this was really necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ruby's standard `require` only loads Ruby files, not folders or anything else. When you say "require 'rexml'", you're actually saying "look for 'rexml.rb' in one of the paths in $: and load it." Thus, "require 'rexml/document'" looks for the file "document.rb" in the folder "rexml" in one of the paths in $:.

Answer (score 6):

In Ruby, `require` requires only a single file.  In many cases, authors of libraries/gems will ensure that that single file requires all other code necessary to use the library, however - see [these lines in the nokogiri library](http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/blob/53a62edb8bf057b1a85e2af8462b01aa3fafee16/lib/nokogiri.rb#L15-24), for instance.  This can vary from library to library, however, and in the case of REXML it appears that you do need to require 'rexml/document'.